# Convert .mp4 video file for playback on camcorder

Tags: video, video-conversion, mpeg4, mjpeg, camcorder

I have a .mp4 file with MPEG4 for video and MP3 for audio that I need to convert to make my camcorder (a cheap one I got off eBay) play it back, but the only problem is that it doesn't accept anything other than a .avi file with MJPEG for video and a codec I haven't heard of called PCM_S16LE 16KHz 256kbps 1CH for audio.

I can't find any method to do this conversion on Google or using Any Video Converter.

Thank You.

Comment: Have you tried Format Factory http://www.pcfreetime.com/ ?

Comment: I found that FormatFactory does have the option for MJPEG and PCM, but with the defaults for the codecs, it wouldn't play but only showed the length of the file. I will tinker and find a solution when I have time, but until then, I would appreciate it if you could post your comment as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We have multiple audio/video converter tools available both paid and free,one of the excellent choice (especially for old phones and DVD ripping) is Format Factory. It has presets for over 100 devices, converts to and from dozens of formats, and allows for advanced tweaking and custom profiles.I suggest you give it a try.You can download the tool from the following link:http://www.pcfreetime.com/